# Ajax request not renewing session?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, session-timeout

On my website, when user is logged in, there is an AJAX request going on every ~20seconds, the requested PHP is working with sesssion (starts with session_start).

I thought that having the website opened + the "infinite" ajax requesting should keep the logged-in user logged-in.

However I got an echo from one of my users, that he gets logged-out after a longer while - how is this possible? Isn't ajax request respectively the requested PHP renewing the Session?

What might cause these logg-outs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not just increase your session timeout???

Comment: This seems to me like a single end user problem. Please, reproduce and share the issue.

Comment: Could it be a javascript error that halted ajax requests, therefore not renewing the session, making it expire? It depends on your website's environment. I think you should provide further info. about. Are there any more requests/actions going on?

Comment: I want session to expire after user closes the browser - therefore I cant set the session time for that long. @Thomas: there are no erros, this is the only action, and the ajax is trying again even if the internet connection is not availabe.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting something like this in your header

```
<?php
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60 * 60); //ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', Mulpitplyer*Seconds);
session_start();
?>
```

Sessions can also drop off if the user has an "unstable" internet conection

Comment: So you think it is caused by the garbage collector? If so, 24*60*60 (desired at least 1day) would be my settings? Where do I set this when I dont have access to PHP.ini ? BTW: How does this affect performance when there will be more users ?

Comment: If you dont have access to your php.ini then set it in php code as i have done above just change it to ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 24 * 60 * 60);, although in my experience its an unstable internet connection

Comment: Is there a fix "fighting" against the unstable in.conn.?

Comment: not from a php perspective, as soon as the connection is gone the session data drops, if you did extend the session somehow it could be a security hole, what would stop someone coming along with the admins session id and accessing data?

Comment: thats what I am thinking too... With the Garbage collector - is it enaught to set it in the PHP? - you know because manual says if there are different values in different scripts the minimal will be used. - shouldnt I rather set it in the .htaccess?

Comment: its up to you really, from the php manual.. The configuration option will keep this new value during the script's execution, and will be restored at the script's ending, my understanding of that is, if they load a page with that on it it will stay at that value for as long as they stay there

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](http://xpapad.wordpress.com/2010/06/19/preventing-session-expiration-with-ajax/), it could be because the browser is caching AJAX requests which could be resolved by including a `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false })` call before your request.

Comment: Nice tip, but I dont think that is causing my problem. Thanks anyway